# Picture Box not displaying image

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I need help in showing the picture box on runtime

```
Private Sub LoadCards()
    Dim Cards As New PictureBox

    For i As Integer = 0 To imglist1.Images.Count - 1
        Cards.Image = imglist1.Images(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using WinForm application or what?

Comment: Yes, I am using WinForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add your picture box to your form first like below :

```
Dim Cards  As New PictureBox
Cards.Width = 100 'or whatever
Cards.Height = 200
Cards.Top = 50 'or whatever
Cards.Left = 50
Me.Controls.Add(Cards)
```

Then do your operation, though the `For` loop here is not much meaningful :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To imglist1.Images.Count - 1
    Cards.Image = imglist1.Images(i)
Next i
```

Comment: The `For`-loop does not make sense. It will always only show the last image of `imglist1.Images`.

Comment: The main reason is that you didn't add your picture box to your form, you should also specify the size & location of your control.

Comment: If this answer helped you, Don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yeah, I will, it just takes 6 minutes before I can award an answer. By the way, how would I create more than 1 pictures box, more like a set?

Comment: You can always post new questions where you can refer your old question which is better then extending the question.